# NodeJs - Puppeteer: Why below setting of page size is not effective?

Tags: node.js, size, puppeteer

I tried to set the page size of PDF and make it to be landscape but fail.
What should I change to make it effective?

I tried to add *page.setViewport* & *isLandscape* lots of time but still not making it effective.

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--enable-font-antialiasing', '--font-render-hinting=medium'], //, '--window-size=1070x1514', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-software-rasterizer'
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT,
    headless: true
    ,isLandscape: true
});

page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setViewport({
    width: 1080,
    height: 1600,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    isLandscape: true
});

// local file
await page.goto(`file:///${ __dirname}/www/index.html`, {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT
});

await page.waitForFunction(() => !!(window.Ext && Ext.isReady && window.App && App.app), {
    polling: LOAD_POLLING,
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT
});
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1080,
    height: 1600,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    isLandscape: true
});

await page.evaluate(
    App.pdf.Builder.create({
        ...
    });
);
await page.waitForFunction(() => App.pdf.Builder.ready || App.pdf.Builder.error, {
    polling: LOAD_POLLING,
    timeout: PAGEBUILD_TIMEOUT
});

await page.pdf({
    path: filePath,
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
        top: '0px',
        right: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    },
    printBackground: true // required for photos otherwise blank
    ,scale: 0.5
});
```

I tried to add `width: '1920px', height: '1080px'` in `page.pdf()` but failed also. (only could make it to be landscape if set in `page.pdf()`)

Comment: So were you or were you not able to make a landscape pdf? (The last line is confusing). Do you get a pdf at all ?(even if not landscaped)

Comment: I can get the portrait PDF without the size that I set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [to the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) you also need to tell `page.pdf` method that you'd like a landscape PDF:

```
await page.pdf({
    landscape: true, // <-- must be set to true to get a landscape PDF
    path: filePath,
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
        top: '0px',
        right: '0px',
        bottom: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    },
    printBackground: true // required for photos otherwise blank
    ,scale: 0.5
});
```

Comment: Hi @Vaviloff, may you help to advise this case which is serious to me, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443568/